# Bevel (edge) only considering one surface

Tags: bevel

[image: Sample Image]

While beveling the first and third edges from the left, only one surface is being considered. Tried applying scale using ctrl+a, still not working

Comment: hello could you please share this part of your object so that we can give a try? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It looks as if there are disconnected/overlapping faces near the top of that image, but as moonboots says we need to see the blend file to be sure.